# How can I manually add outlines to image traced using Image Trace

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-trace

I have an image traced in Black and White mode using Image Trace in Adobe Illustrator. Doing this gives me outlines of which areas of the image will be rendered in white and which will be in black. I know I can adjust the outlines by increasing/reducing the Threshold in the Image Trace window but I want to find out if I can/how to do this manually.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by manually? Do you want to edit the outlines once you hit image trace? Pick the settings that work best for your image. You will not be able to edit the lines manually until you go to object -> expand, make sure to check stroke + fill and hit ok. The object (image) will be B&W and you will be able to move the anchor points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the `Expand` button in the **Control Bar**, across the top of the screen, after using `Image Trace` all the object become standard Illustrator objects which will allow you to adjust their fills and strokes like any other object.